# Converting a numpy string array to integers in base-16

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for a way to convert an array of strings in numpy to the integers they represent in hexadecimal. So in other words, the array version of:

```
int("f040", 16)
```

I can convert a string array to integers base-10 by calling arr.astype(numpy.int32), but I can't see any obvious way to convert them base-16. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
ar = ['f040', 'deadbeaf'] 
int_array = [int(a, 16) for a in ar]
print int_array
```

output:

[61504, 3735928495L]

Comment: You don't need to prefix a with '0x'

Comment: I am aware that list comprehensions can solve the problem, I was wondering if there was a "fast" method in numpy itself analogous to astype.

Comment: @dpitch40 Probably there is not a fast answer, although the list comprehension is only a very short line. Or do you mean performance wise? (numpy is generally about 10 times faster than Python functions).